# Linux mint gdb-8.0.1 tui support?

Tags: linux, gdb, ncurses

I have successfully built gdb-8.0.1 on "Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia"... works great.

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
```

Now trying to recompile with TUI support. Additionally installed

```
libncurses5-dev and libncursesw5-dev
```

still can not make gdb with tui support

```
./configure --enable-tui=yes
make
configure: error: no enhanced curses library found; disable TUI
Makefile:9096: recipe for target 'configure-gdb' failed
```

Did I install the wrong libncurses libs? Are there other packages I need?

Comment: There should be a `config.log` file which shows the error.

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild everything from scratch from another directory? It could probably be that old configuration was cached by some reason.

Comment: Do you have any files named `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so*` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, found /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 and
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5.9

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks good to know. I found log but did not see anything describing the error.

Comment: @ks1322 Thanks, your right! I deleted the extracted folder and re-extracted from gdb-8.0.1.tar.gz again. Apparently you can not run make or ./configure multiple times. It's not self-cleaning. Must delete folder and start with fresh extract. Interesting, Running "make" works but not "make install", maybe a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now trying to recompile with TUI support

Try to rebuild everything from scratch from another directory. It could probably be that old configuration from previous run was cached by some reason.

Comment: While this may work, it would be much better to be able to clear the caches mentioned. How can one do so?

Comment: I would try `make clean` or `git clean` if sources were cloned from git repository.

Comment: This advice works. The ``./configure`` script produces artefacts that ``make clean`` does not remove. For some reason ``git clean -df`` also does nothing. I recommend installing ``libncurses5`` and ``libncurses5-dev``, then re-cloning the sources in a different directly, exactly as OP suggested.